# Firebase iOS not receiving events after re-auth with JWT

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm using the Firebase iOS SDK and part of my app experience is group chat. I have a class for each group chat and store a reference to the firebase object as follows:

```
self.firebaseMessages = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Message/%@", FIREBASE_URL, chat.objectId]];
```

I then observe each event I'm interested in. This works very well. I use custom auth with JWTs and my issue is when the token expires or the user logs out / in and I re-authenticate. At that point, the callbacks stop firing for the events I'm observing unless I completely restart my app. I know the re-auth was successful because I get a success callback and authdata in the AuthEventWithBlock. When I set values, the database updates and other clients receive those updates. It's just the client that re-auth'd that no longer receives updates.

I've dumbed down my security rules to eliminate that as a possibility:

```
"Message": {
      "$message": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
```

I re-auth on the root URL:

```
 Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:FIREBASE_URL];
    [ref authWithCustomToken:responseObject[@"auth_token"] withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAuthData *authData) {
```

I've tried re-auth on each message URL as well. Also tried re-instantiating all of my Firebase objects.

Also note that I am using [ref unauth] on the root to log the user out and to simulate a token expiration.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd imagine that your listeners are being canceled after loss of auth (impossible to verify this with such a terse amount of code). You could verify this by adding a cancel block and logging the cancel errors that occur. You'll need to re-establish the listeners after re-authenticating.

Comment: If the listeners are canceled on loss of auth, that makes sense. I didn't realize that. Obviously if I re-instantiate the Firebase objects, they would go away anyway - so that was an over site on my part. I'm sure re-establishing the listeners will solve the problem so I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kato's comment is the solution. **Make sure to re-establish event listeners if you lose authentication and re-auth.**

Also worth nothing that all of the data will also flow back in when the listeners are re-established. If you're on a screen that streams data from those listeners - like a group chat, you will likely receive data that is already being displayed. Easy enough to handle, though.